# Heroku rake tasks state 'DETAIL: User does not have CONNECT privilege'

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-postgres

I have tried to run `rake db:setup` and get the: `DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.` error.

I have tried to run `GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE dbname TO user;` suggested here: [psql: permission denied for database "dbname" ("User does not have CONNECT privilege.") / "unrecognized role option 'connect'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302398/psql-permission-denied-for-database-dbname-user-does-not-have-connect-privi)

And I still get the error. Is there another command I should be running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku already creates the database for you, and you cant run `rake db:create` or `rake db:drop` because you don't have permissions.
If you want to drop the database, this can be done via:

```
heroku pg:reset DB_NAME
```

If you just want to run the migrations, you can run `rake db:migrate` with no problems.