# Acces denied on rails test database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write the testfiles on my first rails application, but can't seem to communicate with the database. Whenever I try to run "rails test" or anything similar, I get this error:

```
rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 29784
Run options: --seed 45825

# Running:

E

Error:
EmployeeTest#test_the_truth:
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'dataRails'@'localhost' to database 'dataRails_test-3'
    /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `connect'
    /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.3/lib/mysql2/client.rb:90:in `initialize'
```

This is in my database.yml:

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: dataRails_test
  pool: 5
  username: dataRails
  password: Railstest
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

I can log in with the same username and password just fine in the mysql server, so they are correct. Why is the login from this side giving me problems?

Comment: User `dataRails` has login credentials to server but doesn't have access to `dataRails_test-3` database. Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19302501/3543115

Comment: But the dataRails_test-3 db is not even a thing and also: never even defined. It's just one database: dataRails_test. If I have more tests, which also fail because of database reasons, it asks for dataRails_test-1, -2 or -4 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If rails is trying to connect to `dataRails_test-1`, `dataRails_test-2`, ..., `dataRails_test-n` is because you have configured [Parallel Testing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#parallel-testing), which means you are running tests in parallel using a set of Databases.

Check if you have an environment variable like this:

```ruby
PARALLEL_WORKERS=n # Where 'n' is any positive number
```

So, probably the reason of the error you received is because you didn't create all the necessary databases to run tests in parallel. To solve this just run the following command before running tests:

```bash
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:create # Will create the number of databases set on PARALLEL_WORKERS
```

If all the databases were successfully created, now you can try running your test suite:

```bash
rails test
```